# How can I make the workspace switcher in Unity 2D show more than one row of workspaces?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-2d, workspaces

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. Everything works well except the workspaces refuse to form more than one row and I'm use to working with a 2x2 grid.
The dimensionality of the workspace settings **is** reflected in the "desktop expo" behaviour obtained from the button in the unity dock, but **is not** in the Ctrl-Alt- switching. See screenshot:

[image: Sreenshot]

Neither the compiz settings (general options) nor [indicator-workspaces](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/quickly-adjust-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity-with-indicator-workspaces/) seem to be able to properly fix this. From reading around, most other people are **not** having this issue.

Has anyone got some ideas on what has gone wrong and how to fix it?
(n.b. that I'm using Unity 2D)

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround:

First of all, install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

1. Then, launch a terminal and run the command `gnome-panel`.
2. Look for the old style workspace icons. By default, it's located at lower right corner.
3. Right click on it and choose *Preferences*.
4. Set the number of rows, in your case, to 2.
5. Your should get the new workspace changes. Close the window.

Comment: For this to work, you need to install the `gnome-panel` package and dependencies that include the packages `gnome-applets` and `gnome-session-fallback`, but once you've done that, it works fine. +1

Comment: For future reference this still works in 12.04 for those that need to alter the workspace **layout** in Unity 2D.