# Single row of Workspaces with Unity 2d

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d

Using 12.04 with unity **2D** I have the opposite problem [to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52396/how-can-i-make-the-workspace-switcher-in-unity-2d-show-more-than-one-row-of-work) - how can I change from a 2x2 arrangement to having a **single** row of workspaces?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the [work-around listed to use gnome-panel](https://askubuntu.com/a/108833/7143) **does** still work in 12.04. It appears to be only necessary to install gnome-panel:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

The other packages listed are not needed. Once installed, its justs a matter of running gnome-panel on the cli, using its preferences to set the required layout and existing gnome-panel.